# Apache Perl 500 “Internal Server Error” - malformed header from script. Bad header=<!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: perl, cgi-bin

I'm getting an Apache "500 Internal Server Error" even after installing Perl. Running the file from the terminal works fine (`perl hello.pl`).

Perl Mod setup with Apache everything is configured correctly (chmod the file etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print("Hello, World!\n");
```

I am still getting a `500 server error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the apache_error.log and saw

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You need to add a `Content-type` Header to the file.

**Fix**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print("Hello, World!\n");
```